# Fill rows in column A with value of column B if condition in column A is met

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements, exasol

I have a table like:

```
colA    | colB
" "     | 1
"K 111" | 1
"K222"  | 2
" "     | 3
```

Some columns have only a space (" "), some have "K {number}", some have "K{number}".

If colA has only a space I want that value replaced with the one from colB.

So endresult should be:

```
colA    | colB
1       | 1
"K 111" | 1
"K222"  | 2
3       | 3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select (case when colA = ' ' then to_char(col_b)
             else colA
        end) as new_colA
```

If you wanted to be more general, you might use `like`:

```
select (case when colA like 'K%' then colA
             else
        end) as new_colA
```

In an `update`, you would move the `when` condition to a filtering condition:

```
update t
    set colA = to_char(colb)
    where colA = ' ';
```

Comment: Thanks, first code example works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select 
    case when cola = ' ' then to_char(colb) else cola end as cola,
    colb
from mytable
```

Note that all branches of a `case` expression must return values of the same datatype. It seems like `colb` is a number, so this converts it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Or, `DECODE` function (just an alternative to `CASE`):

```
SQL> with test (cola, colb) as
  2    (select 'K 111', 1 from dual union all
  3     select ' '    , 1 from dual union all
  4     select 'K222' , 2 from dual union all
  5     select ' '    , 3 from dual
  6    )
  7  select decode(cola, ' ', to_char(colb), cola) cola,
  8         colb
  9  from test;

COLA             COLB
---------- ----------
K 111               1
1                   1
K222                2
3                   3

SQL>
```

Comment: NVL replaces a NULL. In the OP's data model, they use a single space for NULL. NVL doesn't deal with that. Perhaps you want to wrap `cola` within some sort of `NULLIF` call first.

Comment: Ah, a *space* ... looking at the example, I was fooled by double quotes enclosing "nothing" and *translated* that (in my mind) as if it was a NULL. Completely wrong. Thank you, @mathguy. Rewritten to DECODE, just as an alternative to CASE.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to update the value using `IS NULL` check as follows:

```
update your_table
   set colA = to_char(colB)
 where trim(colA) is null;
```

Empty string in Oracle is considered as null.